# loging to gmail using OAuth to retrieve account details in trigger.io

Tags: google-app-engine, trigger.io

I want to loging in and retrieve all information using Gmail id in trigger.io .Is it possible with trigger.io ?

I had tried to find out module but unfortunately i didn't get anything related with Google api .

Thanks in advance

Gaurav

Comment: Hi Gaurav, can you give us some more information about what data you're trying to get about the user? Is it for the main user on an Android device, or anyone with a Google ID? Have you see Google's OAuth service?

Comment: Hello James , I am trying to log in with Google in Trigger.io , And i did it thanks . I have made my own module for it with the help of child browser .